# Get difference between relations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas, relation_between_countries:

```
    country_from   country_to  points
1   Albania        Austria     10
2   Denmark        Austria     5   
3   Austria        Albania     2 
4   Greece         Norway      4   
5   Norway         Greece      5
```

I'm trying to get the difference between the points of the relations, as this:

```
country_from_or_to   country_to_or_from  difference
Albania              Austria             8
Denmark              Austria             
Greece               Norway              -1
```

Do you have any ideas how to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
cols = ['country_from','country_to']
#sort values in columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(sorted, axis=1)
#get difference
df['difference'] = df.groupby(cols)['points'].diff(-1)
print (df)
  country_from country_to  points  difference
1      Albania    Austria      10         8.0
2      Austria    Denmark       5         NaN
3      Albania    Austria       2         NaN
4       Greece     Norway       4        -1.0
5       Greece     Norway       5         NaN
```

Also is possible replace `NaN` to empty space, but get mixed values in column - numeric with strings, so some function can return weird outputs:

```
cols = ['country_from','country_to']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(sorted, axis=1)
df['difference'] = df.groupby(cols)['points'].diff(-1).fillna('')
print (df)
  country_from country_to  points difference
1      Albania    Austria      10          8
2      Austria    Denmark       5           
3      Albania    Austria       2           
4       Greece     Norway       4         -1
5       Greece     Norway       5
```